# User friendly way to create a screenshot from a website

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, web

my visitors would like to be able to save some sites as an image-file, so they can look at it anytime offline. They visit my site with different devices (tablets, phones, pcs..) and different browsers so relying on third-party software is not a great option. (the imagefile format is pretty much irrelevant btw)

I would like my server to achieve this task for the users;  Preferably with javascript, ajax, php otherwise anything else, if it's easy. The pages are dynamically created, but relatively simple html, some text, some jpg-images, no css - nothing fancy (like animated gifs or flash). the dynamical creation doesnt require session cookies or something, just url (and maybe get) information.

I dont have much of an idea how to do this - when I google i just find solutions for endusers, not for me. The only possibility i know of right now is to use the php-png functionality. That way my visitors can click on a link and be directed to a dynamic png file that they can download. But I'd have to "write" the pngs manually, php-png cant convert html to png, can it?

I only tried php-png once, ~5 years back; I remember it being a bit laborious. Is there a library for easier and extended functionality?

Everything summed up in one question: Whats the easiest way to make an image from a html website? It should be as easy as possible for the user primarly, and then for me.

;) Extra Credits: in case I find something that can create images dynamically. How do I get any Browser to automatically download a picture permanently in the download directory instead of showing just a temporarily saved preview?

Comment: don't include the "thank you" note; bare questions are better.

Comment: I don't think that an image file is a good way to save content.

Comment: In my specific case, image saving is necessary, there is no other option. but i didnt want to waste ur time by explaining it in detail. Also, imo it's great for DAUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pages you want people to download as images are your own, and you control the server that is serving them, you can use [php-imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to build the "screen-shot" images server-side (so users would choose between an HTML version and a single-image version; or would click on a button in the HTML version to download the image version). First you define a canvas, then you render text blocks and images on to it, and finally you save that as a PNG or JPG image.

Imagemagick does not offer much flexibility in the way of fonts; you may want to render the text-blocks using [imagegetttftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) instead, and then add those to the imagemagick image.

Since building images in this way can be server-side expensive, you would want to cache results.

Comment: (for other answerers: i have server control, fonts are not important)
That sounds promising! It's still a bit manual, but it can solve my problem. Thx for the tipps!

Answer (score 2):

PDF's would be a better solution as they're scalable and can include hyperlinks. The process would be to render a page using a headless browser and output the rendered PDF. A quick Google revealed some interesting possibilities:

1. Dompdf: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/
2. WebKit/KHTML based renderer: https://github.com/mreiferson/php-wkhtmltox
3. Google Chrome Webkit Backed: http://phantomjs.org/ + https://github.com/diggin/php-PhantomjsRunner

Comment: good idea - and also points OP to the tools for rendering offline / headless, which can be applied to making images as well. Btw, you surely mean 'webkit backend' as the 3rd option...